# jquery: Math failed

Tags: jquery, math, logic

The following code loops through the sprite image, moving -120 every second, but for some reason it's jumps from 0 to -120 and then to 120 instead to -240

```
    thismarginLeft = $this.css("margin-left").replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    if(thismarginLeft < -360 || thismarginLeft == 0){
            thismarginLeft = thismarginLeft - 120;
            if(thismarginLeft < -360){
              thismarginLeft = 0;
            }
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FDRmv/1/

Comment: Please include all of the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As yahermann said the problem came from the replace method that was removing the '-' in front of your margin-left css.

You can even use 'parseInt' if you don't want to use 'replace' : (Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/FDRmv/2/)

```
var internalMiniPoster;
$(".miniPosterImg").hover(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    internalMiniPoster = setInterval(function () {
        thismarginLeft = parseInt($this.css("margin-left"),10); // always use a radix
        if (thismarginLeft < -360 || thismarginLeft == 0) {
            thismarginLeft = thismarginLeft - 120;
            if (thismarginLeft < -360) {
                thismarginLeft = 0;
            }
        }
        $this.css("margin-left", thismarginLeft + "px");
    }, 1000);
}, function () {
    clearInterval(internalMiniPoster);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

hard to figure out exactly what you're doing.

but perhaps you meant this:

```
    if(thismarginLeft > -360){
```

instead of this:

```
    if(thismarginLeft < -360 || thismarginLeft == 0){
```

and also, include - in your regexp:

```
    thismarginLeft = $this.css("margin-left").replace(/[^0-9\-]/g,'');
```